# Which cruise altitude is prefered in engine-out operations of Boeing airplanes?

Tags: engine-failure, altitude, cruise

On Engine Out Operation in Boeing Airplanes, which altitude is preferable, the OPT Altitude, the MAX Altitude or the RECOM Altitude of the ENG OUT CRZ Page?

Answer (score 5):

You'd typically drift down to your max single-engine altitude, which means essentially that max continuous power on the operating engine is sufficient for level flight at that altitude.  Higher than that, you have a slow descent going in order for the thrust you have to maintain the recommended driftdown airspeed.

In general, there wouldn't be any advantage to descending lower than this until you need to do so for approach and landing, so you'd probably remain at that max altitude.  As you burn off fuel, your max engine-out altitude would *slowly* increase so (hypothetically) you could actually step-climb up a little bit if you were going to be at that new Single Engine cruise altitude long enough, but in practice you'd need to lose the engine a LONG way from landing before the idea of step-climbing up to a higher SE cruise altitude would make practical sense.

The "Max" altitude is only reachable with the thrust of 2 engines, and the "OPT" altitude is probably well above what your max SE altitude is anyway -- it's optimum for cruising ***with both engines operating***, after all.  Granted, a sufficiently high Cost Index and/or strange winds can pull the Optimum altitude down, but in 99% of the cases, Optimum is going to be well above Max Single Engine altitude.

Comment: `max single-engine altitude` - in a 747? ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's not un-heard-of for a 747 in an ultra-long-haul op to step or cruise climb on 3 engines.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject My (jokey) point was that Ralphs answer only addresses twins.  It ignores the 747 when the OP asks for "Boeing".

Comment: What about a B-47? Or B-52?

Comment: The preferable altitude is the one you ve been recleared  to! Especially on airways over congested airspace. Also you have to consider wind and temperature if you are going to a looong ETOPS before deciding to go for MAX or RECMD.

Comment: @Houba  In the case of having lost an engine, you will have declared an emergency so you'll probably be cleared for whatever altitude or block of altitude you need.  You may well also turn out of the tracks so that you can petform the gradual driftdown descent clear of traffic.  But "not descending" is hardly an option regardless of ATC when that motor quits.  You're correct that temp & winds are used in the FMC calculations that give you ECON + driftdown speeds & the various altitudes.

Comment: @Simon -- aye ;)

Comment: @egid -- BUFFs need new engines anyway :P

Comment: @RalphJ Thanks for the answer... I didn't wrote my question properly, because, when I wrote about the OPT, MAX and RECMD, I was assuming that it referred to the OPT, MAX and RECMD single Engine Altitude that the FMC displays when pressing the ENG OUT key, so the info shown in that case will be based on single engine operation, according to the FCOM Volume 2. Sorry for that...
Anyway, if the FMC give us an OPT engine out altitude, and a RECMD engine out altitude, shouldn't be preferable to use them, at least over the ETP of  an ETOPS 180 scenario, for example?

Comment: That's different FMC software than I'm used to, then.  Having Optimum + Recommended + Max altitudes ***all on the SE Cruise page*** is a new one for me.  Most curious how an "optimum" altitude differs from a "recommended" altitude.

Comment: @RalphJ The difference between the OPT and the RECMD Altitude for Single Engine and All Engine is predicted wind. I worked with some airplanes with the Honeywell Pegasus FMC, and you can uplink or entered wind prediction for each waypoint, on the Active Flight Plan, with 4 different altitudes for each waypoint. WIth that information the FMC calculates the recommended Altitude based on wind.

Comment: @aiglesiasn  Thanks, that makes good sense.  I'm used to a Smiths FMC rather than Honeywell, so different functionality there.